# Condition number of matrix sum

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to tackle the following question (taken from TAU test):

> Let $A$ be a matrix such that $AA^T=I$. Find whether there is a matrix $B$ such that $\text{cond}(A+B)<\text{cond}(A)$. If there is such B, give an example. If there is no such B, prove.

Iv'e tried to use the definition of condition number and reduce the problem to square matrices, but to no avail.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: How do you define the condition number of a non-square matrix?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Iv'e seen some definitions here at MSE, but after reviewing my notebook again, Iv'e found that we work only with square matrices.

Comment: @user1551, it is actually non trivial - If I choose $B=-A$ then $\text{cond}(A+B)=\text{cond}(0)=\infty$, which is at least big as $\text{cond}(A)$. Nothing is known about $B$.

Comment: @Galc127 Thanks. You're right. I've misread the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is real, then $A$ is orthogonal. If we consider $||.||_2$, then $cond_2(A)=1$, that is the minimum of $cond_2(.)$ and $B$ does not exist.

If $A$ is not real and if $cond_2(A)>1$, then choose $B=-A+I$.